# Sample data from combination of two probability distributions

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, scipy, numpy

I want to generate a mock catalogue. I have access to two independent sets of real data and I want to use their properties to make the mock catalogue: 
The first one contains the information from **magnitude** and **redshift** ($z$) of galaxies, while the second data set has **magnitude** and **weighted ellipticity** of galaxies.

In my final simulated catalogue, I want to generate **redshift** and **weighted ellipticity** for a set of randomly generated galaxies. I would like to use the underlying properties of **magnitude** versus **redshift** and **magnitude** versus **weighted ellipticity**. However I also have a well-define formula that discribes the distribution of redshift and the functionality is given as following (`GeneralRandom` is a class that is able to generate a random sample follows the given distribution $p(z)$):

```
def p(z):
    z0=1./3.;eta=1.0
    value=eta*(z**2)*np.exp(-1*(z/z0)**eta)/scipy.special.gamma(3./eta)/z0**3 
    return value

catalogue_generate=GeneralRandom(x=np.arange(0.0, 1.5, .001), p_func=p, Nrl=10000) 
ng=24000
catalogue_generate.set_pdf(np.arange(0.0, 1.5, .001), catalogue_generate.p_val, 10000)
redshift=catalogue_generate.random( ng)[0]
redshift=random.sample(redshift, ng)
```

The sample with input **redshift distribution** is produced by above procedure.

I also used `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` to estimate the probability distribution of **magnitude** versus **redshift** and **magnitude** versus **weighted ellipticity** for two available data sets.

Now I am confused how I could combine the `kde` computed from two distribution and obtain just my interested parameter in the mock catalogue, `weighted ellipticity` from the `sampled redshift`? The plot is illustrating the Gaussian KDE estimated for two data sets. I don't know how I could independently use the output of `stats.gaussian_kde` to just insert computed `redshift` and obtain `magnitude` and then from estimated `magnitude` before, and estimated second KDE estimate the `weighted ellipticities`?[image]

Is it statistically correct to say the problem looks like this: $$P(w_\epsilon)=\int P(Mag|w_\epsilon)\int P(z|Mag)P(z)dz$$

I also don't know computationally, how it should be done?!! I will appreciate if somebody can describe how I could tackle my problem and a bit of python programming tips or introducing useful libraries.